# Regex to extract variable number of key value pairs

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Though I have found quite a few SO posts talking about using regex to extract key/value pairs, I was not able to find a solution for my particular use case.

I have key-value pairs like this:

```
{date=2020-07-22, labelId=100000004}
```

That will vary in the number of key/value pairs.

I would like to have a regular expression to extract these as keys and values"groups" like
groups[1:] = "date", "2020-07-22", "labelID", "100000004

This sort of matches correctly for the first match,

`([a-zA-Z0-9]+)=((?:[^\\\\\"]|\\\\.)*+)`

...but I need a way to "split" on the comma

In regex gurus able to help me out with this one?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just exclude the comma from the value part. When you use `re.finditer()` it will return all the matches.

Comment: Or split the string first on the commas, then apply a regexp to each string in the list.

Comment: Try `dict(re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)=([\d-]+)', text))`, see https://ideone.com/ktdmwD. Why do you try to match a string that does not contain quotes allowing escaped quotes?

Answer (score 2):

Use a pattern that excludes `{` and `=` from the key, and `}` and `,` from the value of each match.

```
import re

data = '{date=2020-07-22, labelId=100000004}'
regex = '([^{=]+)=([^,}]+)'

print(re.findall(regex, data))
```

Note that this regex doesn't allow for quoting the key and/or value to let them include the delimiter characters. That makes using regular expressions much more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
import re
text = "{date=2020-07-22, labelId=100000004}"
print(dict(re.findall(r'([a-zA-Z0-9]+)=([\d-]+)', text)))
# => {'date': '2020-07-22', 'labelId': '100000004'}
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ktdmwD) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CbOtQz/1).

*Regex details*:

- `([a-zA-Z0-9]+)` - Group 1: any one or more letters or digits
- `=` - a `=` char
- `([\d-]+)` - Group 2: one or more digits or `-`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do without a regex here:

```py
text = '{date=2020-07-22, labelId=100000004}'
print(dict([x.split('=') for x in text.strip('{}').split(', ')]))
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##NcxBCoMwEEDRfU8xu8mASkwLXeUAnqG4sCbiQIghziJFPHuklP7146ePrFu81yq@CFjAw03irdFGt/rZGtNAmN4@DM72@tfjxFvKHEU5nkW9SrenwKLQIsGyZSjAEb6/bpfMSeFxIv1RA0gjUa0X).

That is, remove braces on both ends of the string, split with comma-space, and then split with `=`.

**Results**: `{'date': '2020-07-22', 'labelId': '100000004'}`